# Do I really have to reload my page twice?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, session

I am currently working on a project including the Facebook SDK. I already made it to Login/Logout myself using the javascript code.

I'm using an AJAX POST request to save the userID and the name from the response in a Session.

The problem here is, that I actually have to reload the page twice, the first time to get the POST parameters and save them into a $_SESSION.
The second refresh is needed to load the Session.

Is there a clean way to avoid that?

javascript: `$.post( "login.php", { id:userID, name:response.name } );`

login.php: 
`$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];`
`$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['id'];`

I appreciate every kind of help. Thank you.

**edit:**
I would like to give the user who logged in with facebook additional oppurtunities on my website. The only way I know how to do this is with a Session in PHP. Whenever he logged in I created a Session who said that a person is logged in.

Now I have to do the same with a facebook login. It worked local with the PHP SDK already, but the webspace does not support that kind of SDK. That is why I have to dodge to the javascript one.
Is there another way to make sure a person is logged?

Comment: why would you even do that? what for? with the javascript sdk, you do not need any page refresh. and why would you reload the page to load the session while you already got all the information in javascript?

Comment: No idea what the actual question is.

Comment: most likely you've a misplaced session array. check with `isset()` first and that the session is started first, and in all pages using sessions

Comment: You should use JavaScript SDK for this;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AJAX,
So you can avoid reloading of Page,

```
<?php    
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];}
    if (isset($_GET['userID'])) {$_SESSION['userID'] = $_GET['userID'];}

    if(isset ($_POST['name']  ) && isset ($_POST['userID'])){
        $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name']; 
        $_SESSION['userID']=  $_POST['userID'];
    }else{
        $_SESSION['userID'] = 0;
    } 
?>
```

and javascript code is:

```
$.post( "/login.php", { id:userID, name:response.name } );
```